# ORACLE SQL to ANSI SQL conversion issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling to convert this `greatest()` oracle function into ANSI SQL..

```
SELECT sum( case when table1.sale_Id Is Null And
table2.status In ('D1','E1','P1') And 
table3.Code In ('A','B','C') Then
(Case When (Greatest(table2.date1),table4.CALENDAR_DATE) <=
Least(table3.date1),(table4.CALENDAR_DATE+(Nvl(table1.YEAR_PERCENTAGE,100)/100*365)-1)) ) Then 
Round((table1.AMT/Round((nvl(table1.YEAR_PERCENTAGE,100)/100*365),2))*
((Least(table3.date1),(table4.CALENDAR_DATE+(nvl(table1.YEAR_PERCENTAGE,100)/100*365)-1))+1)- 
(Greatest(table2.date1),table4.CALENDAR_DATE) )),2) End)End)

FROM
  table1,
  table2,


  table3,
  table4  
WHERE
  ( table1.b_key=table2.c_key  )
  AND  ( table1.d_key=table3.f_key  )
  AND  ( table1.g_key=table4.h_key  )
```

Comment: SQL is  a language used by many databases including Oracle.  Your question doesn't make sense.  The query is *already* in SQL.

Comment: There are a couple of Oracle functions in the code like GREATEST() and LEAST() which I am trying to convert to SQL

Comment: analytic function are not part of the ANSI SQL, you'll need to migrate them from a specific DB to another specific one

Comment: That's an extremely dense piece of code. Could you explain the business logic you're trying to implement, which would make it easier for us to understand your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greatest isn't being used properly in the example above anyway:

```
Greatest(table2.date1)
```

Greatest is used for a list.  If your list only has 1 item in it, then the greatest element is that item.  So in this case, you can just replace it with this:

```
table2.date1
```

Least works the same way.  These are intrarow operations and take multiple parameters in from that row (unlike their MAX/MIN counterparts).